# How to vertically center android TimePicker on the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-timepicker

Consider the following layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`TimePicker` is placed on the top of the screen, I want to vertically center it.

For example, with `TextView` I would add `android:gravity="center"`, but it doesn't work for `TimePicker`.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the width & height of the `TimePicker` as `wrap_content` in order to center it within the `LinearLayout` with `android:gravity="center"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner" />
</LinearLayout>
```